# How to keep type safety for an aliased column in Jooq?

Tags: alias, jooq

Let's say I want to select the max value of a specific field:

```
getContext().select( ..., //several fields
                    DSL.max(MY_TABLE.SCORE).as("max_score"))
            .from(MY_TABLE)
            .where(...)
            .groupBy(...);
```

I fetch the results, and now I want to get the values of a specific record, so I do:

```
Integer maxScore = (Integer) record.get("max_score");
```

This is working just fine, but I have 2 issues with this approach:

1. Type safety is lost - I must cast the value to `Integer`.
2. Although this field will never be null, Jooq is not aware of this. If I define maxScore as `int` instead of `Integer`, I get a warning on this line:
   `Unboxing of 'record.get("max_score")' may produce 'NullPointerException'`.
   For table's "not-null" fields, I don't get this warning.

Is there a way to overcome these issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Type safety is lost - I must cast the value to Integer.

You can just assign it to a local variable:

```java
Field<Integer> maxScore = max(MY_TABLE.SCORE).as("max_score");
```

Use it like this:

```java
.select(..., maxScore)
.from(...)
```

And then:

```java
record.get(maxScore);
```

> If I define maxScore as int instead of Integer, I get a warning [...]

The warning is likely to go away with the above approach. While [`Record.get(String)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Record.html#get(java.lang.String)) returns `@Nullable Object`, [`Record.get(Field<T>)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Record.html#get(org.jooq.Field)) just returns `T` (inheriting `T`'s nullability, which is likely to be unspecified).

Comment: Indeed, your solution solved both issues, thanks!!!